# Android: ActionBar will not change its style?

Tags: java, android

I'm following the Android Documentation and have correctly copied this code:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme"
        parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
        parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I've set the activities manifest to "CustomTheme" and have the right information in strings.xml so I don't see what the problem would be. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try change "android:actionBarStyle" to "actionBarStyle"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the android: tag and also, you have to set the Parent ActionBar to AppCompat's ActionBar.

```
<style name="CustomTheme"
       parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```